# WaveletScalogram in polar coordinates

Tags: graphics, data, visualization, wavelet-analysis

For given dataset

```
data = Re[Zeta[1/2 + I Range[0, 100, 0.01]]];
```

It is nice that Mathematica can plot data in both Cartesian and Polar coordinates.

```
SetOptions[ListPolarPlot, Joined -> True];
#[data] & /@ {ListLinePlot, ListPolarPlot}
```

[image]

WaveletScalogram is an insightful glance in temporal data:

```
cwd = ContinuousWaveletTransform[data, GaborWavelet[6], {4, 12}, WaveletScale -> 100];
ws = WaveletScalogram[cwd, All, Re, ColorFunction -> "CherryTones"]
```

[image]

**Is it possible to somehow visualize it in Polar coordinates?**

I would try to extract the data from underlying Graphics, but it is a raster

```
ws[[1]] // Head
ws[[1, 1]] // Dimensions
```

> ```
> Raster
> {48, 5001}
> ```

The only thing that comes to mind is ImageTransformation but I don’t think it is an efficient way (will be hard to scale the axis, etc.). Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: In Mathematica wavelets data is stored at ContinuousWaveletData or DiscreteWaveletData. You can check the doc. You can try InverseContinuousWaveletTransform[cwd] // ListPolarPlot to polar plot the resulted wavelet. the Properties of the data are "DataChannels", "DataDimensions", "DataMean", "DataWrapper", "LinearScalogramFunction", "ListPlot", "LogScalogramFunction", "Octaves", "Properties", "SampleRate", "Scales", "Voices", "Wavelet", "WaveletIndex", "WaveletScale". If you see the properties there is no polar plot by default.

Answer (score 10):

I found a way to do this thanks to the more simple question I posted here:

[**Wrapping ArrayPlot or MatrixPlot around a circle**](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/128068)

but it **takes a very long time to compute**. So I will post the answer but **I hope someone will post a faster solution**.

```
cwd = ContinuousWaveletTransform[data, GaborWavelet[6], {4, 12}, WaveletScale -> 100];
ws = WaveletScalogram[cwd, All, Re, ColorFunction -> "CherryTones"];

SectorChart[
 Map[Style[{1, 100}, ColorData["SunsetColors"][#]] &, 
  ws[[1, 1]][[All, 1 ;; -1 ;; 10]], {2}], PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
 ChartStyle -> EdgeForm[None], Background -> Black]
```

[image]

So this is beautiful and it **looks exactly as I need**. But it **took so very long** and I would **really appreciate and wait if someone posts a faster solution**.

Comment: Looks like your polar axis goes to the left. You should flip the image horizontally.

Answer (score 8):

We can visualize the wavelet scalogram using [`ListPolarPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListPolarPlot.html)

```
data = Re[Zeta[1/2 + I Range[0, 100, 0.01]]];
cwd = ContinuousWaveletTransform[data, GaborWavelet[6], {4, 12}, WaveletScale -> 100];

ListPolarPlot[Abs@Reverse[Last /@ cwd[All]], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

> [image: Plot]

Additionally we can see the scalogram in 3D using [`ListPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListPlot3D.html):

```
 ListPlot3D[Abs@Reverse[Last /@ cwd[All]], PlotRange -> All, 
            Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "AtlanticColors", 
            Ticks -> {Automatic, None, Automatic}, 
            AxesLabel -> {"time", "octaves", "magnitude"}, Boxed -> False]
```

> [image: Plot2]

Note: The usage of `AxesLabel` in the second plot is just an example.

Comment: @Darya Is this the solution ?

Comment: Thanks, Nicola, this is interesting, but I hoped to see something reminiscent of original WaveletScalogram visual in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 6):

So, the scalogram is a raster, so what? Why does it deter you from just wrapping it around the pole?

```
ws = WaveletScalogram[cwd, All, Re, ColorFunction -> "CherryTones", 
  Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> None, AspectRatio -> 1]

ImageTransformation[ws, {(ArcTan @@ (0.5 - #) + Pi)/(2 Pi),2 Norm[0.5 - #]} &]
```

[image: Polar scalogram]

Comment: I think this ought to be the accepted answer.